# Auto rename a file if already present in s3 using java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I upload files to AWS S3 using java SDK.
I want to auto rename the file if it is already present in the bucket.

Example : if foo/bar is already present, i want to rename it to foo/bar(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to configure your S3 bucket with versioning.  This will automatically keep every version of a file when it is changed.  In the console, you'll be able to see older versions by clicking the Show Versions button.  Note that the old version will not actually be renamed, but it's still accessible.

If you need to rename the old file, you'll need to do it yourself.  You can follow these steps:

1. choose a name for the file
2. call [`AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObjectMetadata(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectMetadataRequest)) to check if the file exists; append a version number and try again, until it fails
3. copy the file to the last name with version number checked
4. upload the new file under the original name